# Kotlin: Generic in Enum

Tags: kotlin, generics, lambda, graph, enums

I'm aware that you can do the following in Kotlin:

```
enum class Pickers(val fu: (Int) -> Int) {
    LINEAR({ it }),
    QUADRATIC({it*it})
}
```

Can something similar also be done if the function-value needs a generic? In my use-case the function takes a graph, whose type of vertices has to be generic.

Comment: I just got the idea I could just use `Any`. Is this the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) for that purpose:

```
sealed class Pickers<T>(val fu: (T) -> Int) {
    object LINEAR : Pickers<Int>({ it })
    object QUADRATIC : Pickers<Int>({ it * it })
    object STR : Pickers<String>({ it.toInt() })
}
```